# WHMCS Six Theme - how to include home-shortcuts in all pages?

Tags: html, whmcs

I am customising the Six theme in WHMCS and am using the home-shortcuts menu as a secondary menu. However this is only showing on the home page? Any ideas how i can show it on all WHMCS pages? I cannot seem to find any information on this? It is coded in the header.tpl.

[Here is my site](https://www.sitewidedesign.co.uk/hosting)

Any information would be most appreciated.

Regards
Donna

Comment: Looks like you now have the secondary menu on all WHMCS pages. Would you mind self-answering the question if you found the way to do it? It'd be useful for other people searching on how to do this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this was rectified by changing the `<base href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/" />` at the top of the header.tpl file to `{if $systemurl}<base href="{$systemurl}" />
    {/if}`

The full post and suggestions by the WHMCS community can be found [Here](https://forums.whmcs.com/showthread.php?114155-Six-Theme-using-home-shortcuts-on-all-pages-as-menu).